# Python sample function TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python

i GOT this ERROR when doing sampling stratify of a sample dataframe
code is like this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    A=['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'],
    B=range(20)


 ))


df.sample(n=100, weights='A',replace=True)
```

it gives me this error:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

anyone can help?

Comment: Weights are supposed to be numeric.  What are you wanting the weights to do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site!

I've checked the issue, it's because you are trying to create a sample using a str variable.`(df['A'])`. `df.sample` cannot create a sample by assigning weights to categorical variable.

I made a small work around i.e.,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict( A=['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'], B=range(20) ))

#converting the text into categorical codes which are in numeric
df['cat'] = df.A.astype('category').cat.codes

#creating a sample using newly created column
Output = df.sample(n=100,weights = 'cat',replace=True)
```

Output would have 100 records and created using 'cat' for weights.

Comment: But these cat codes are more or less arbitrary, right? Why use them as weights?

Comment: I'm trying to convert each category into a specific number based the cat values weights are assigned. Which is in turn similar to using A.